# Find minimum GCD of a pair of elements in an array

Tags: number-theory, factoring, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

> Given an list of elements, I have to find the MINIMUM GCD possible
>   between any two pairs of the array in least time complexity.

Example

Input

```
list=[7,3,14,9,6]
```

Output

```
1
```

Explanation

```
min gcd can be of pair(7,3)
```

My naive solution-

```
I am just considering pairs of elements one by one to find the min gcd.
Is there any formula or efficient way to find out min gcd?
```